# gulp-autoprefixer simply doesn't work

Tags: css, gulp, autoprefixer

Wasted over 3 days of troubleshooting; have gotten nowhere further. Appreciate any assistance at this point. Here's my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('prefix', function() {
    var prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

    gulp.src(path.join(__dirname, 'app/styles/assets/**/*.css'))
        .pipe(prefixer({ browsers: [ '> 1%' ] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./');
});
```

I placed a single .css file in the specified source directory and added properties/values that would require prefixing, like: transform, column-count and the 'flex' value of the display property.

When run, gulp gives no errors, no file is modified, pretty much nothing happens. I've tried specifying a path to an output file, removing the options from the prefixer() call, hard-coding values into the .src() and .dest() methods, running the whole command in a singular file, inside a sequence runner, reinstalled the module, updated packages and more.

I've read the docs inside and out, am following them to a 'T', and even contacted the module author to look at my code, and he stated it looked fine to him. I simply cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like some of your parentheses aren't closed.  I've never used gulp before, but I imagine it's like most other things that use parentheses?

Comment: I didn't cut and paste directly from my script, as it's well over 400+ lines. But the JS parser throws no errors, so in the event I did not close a paren above, apologies, but all syntax in the executing code is proper.

Comment: No problem.  At least we eliminated the easiest answer lol.

Comment: I notice you didn't put it in a gulp task. Could you try doing that? (Although I do not think that is necessarily the issue). You can reference their example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer)

Comment: Good point. Ugh. I'm so derailed at the moment, that I'm not even cutting and pasting over what I have properly. lol. OK. I added it in the task (as it was) for visual reference. Thanks. I tell ya, when I figure out what the cause of this issue is.... there shall be comeuppance to pay! :)

Comment: use gulp-print to find out if at all the css is being picker or not

Comment: @AaronMartone you didn't really follow the example correctly. Try returning the `gulp.src`. Also I would define the prefixer outside of the task.

Comment: gulp-print is showing nothing in the pipe, which would explain auto-prefixer not erroring or changing any files. I dumped the 'src' var and it shows: 'C:\Server\web\com.aaronmartone\www\build\assets\styles\**\*.css'. Seems offhand like a valid glob path. Has worked fine with previous gulp.src() methods when specifying files... (note stack overflow doesn't show this comment right, but the end of the path above ends with [star] [star] [backslash] [star] [dot] css.

Comment: OK, I think we're getting somewhere. My default task (not shown) uses the 'run-sequence' module to run gulp tasks in sequence. For whatever reason, run-sequence is not compatible with gulp-autoprefixer. Because I temporarily ran 'gulp prefix' (the name of the prefixing task), and it worked as expected.